# Use babel-loader and raw-loader together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have webpack config

```
{
    // ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                resource: {
                    not: [/node_modules/, /raw-loader/],
                    and: [/\.js$/]
                },
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Some component

```
import React from 'react';
import { H1 } from '../../../components/Typography';

const Example = () => {
    return <H1>H1 — Header</H1>;
};

export default Example;
```

And file that imports this example component

```
import ExampleH1Code from 'raw-loader!./examples/h1';
import ExampleH1 from './examples/h1';
```

Babel applies to both ExampleH1 and ExampleH1Code. But i want ExampleH1Code to be raw ES6 text ExampleH1 working component to render on page.

Is it possible? Thanks